# Automatically running a python script after boot?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have written a small python script in Ubuntu 13.10, that when run opens 4 terminals and displays some useful information, is it possible for me to get this to run automatically after I login, I have tried a couple of methods but they all involve it running at start up and this wont leave the terminals displayed.

Answer (score 4):

## Bootup:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Add:

```
@boot cd /home/user/; python script.py
```

## Login:

Edit one of these files:

- nano /etc/profile.d/myscript.sh
- ~/.bash_login

And add:

```
cd /home/user; python script.py
```

## Graphical login:

```
nano ~/.xinitrc
```

Add:

```
eval(cd /home/user; python script.py) &
```

## Ubuntu-Gnome specific login:

```
nano ~/.gnomerc
```

Comment: His Ubuntu probably uses gnome, so mentioning `.gnomerc` would complete your answer.